# Fractional exponentiation with different bases

Tags: asymptotics, fractional-iteration

The standard analytic tetration base $b>e^{1/e}$, $F_b$ is the unique analytic function defined everywhere on $ℂ$ except on the ray from -2 to -∞ such that $F_b(0)=1$, $F_b(\overline z) = \overline{F_b(z)}$ and $F_b(z+1)=b^{F(z)}$, and  $\lim_{y→∞} F_b(x+iy) = L_b$ where $L_b$ is the unique fix-point of base $b$ logarithm in the upper half-plane [(Paulsen and Cowgill 2017)](http://myweb.astate.edu/wpaulsen/tetration2.pdf).

The $c$th iteration of exponentiation base $b$, $\mathrm{exp}_b^c(x) = F_b(F_b^{-1}(x)+c)$.

Let $a$ and $b$ be real numbers above $e^{1/e}$, and $c < d$ be real numbers.  Do we have $\lim_{x→∞}\frac{\mathrm{exp}_a^c(x)} {\mathrm{exp}_b^d(x)} = 0$ ?
(Note that either the limit is 0 or it does not exist.)

In other words, we want to know whether if $c < d$, then $c$th iteration of exponentiation grows asymptotically slower then $d$th iteration of exponentiation, even for fractional $c$ and $d$ and exponentiation using different bases (that are $>e^{1/e}$).

A broader question about naturalness of growth rates related to tetration is [linked here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/281619/analytic-tetration-and-natural-rates-of-growth).  The relation with this question is that if the above limit holds, it gives evidence that fractional exponentiation provides a natural growth rate intermediate between (essentially) quasipolynomial and quasiexponential.  Conversely, if the limit does not hold, then unless we have a reason to prefer a particular base (or use another construction altogether), that suggests that despite existence of analytic tetration, we have not convincingly found a natural approximately half-exponential growth rate (if there is one).

Comment: I contacted an author of the cited paper (William Paulsen), and he conjectures the answer to be yes.

Comment: However, since we do not have a proof, the question remains open.

Comment: The answer to this question turns out to be far more interesting than one would expect.  If one assumes Kneser's solution for real values of c and d, then there are cases where the two bases a<>b, and for arbitrarily large x then even if c<d, sometimes
$$\exp_a^c(x)>\exp_b^d(x)$$
This can only happen if c is only a little bit smaller than d, say 0.0001 or so.    I will post more details later, and give some counter examples.  This is somewhat related to a mathstack question I posted some years ago; https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/208996/half-iterate-of-x2c